# Javascript to image cycle

Tags: javascript

Simple request, but I don't know how to do it. I've got a series of 10 images (image0.gif, image1.gif image2.gif etc...) that need to change to the next image in the sequence (cycling around after 9) when another image is pressed. This is what I have so far...

```
 <html>  
    <head></head>
    <body bgcolor="#808080">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var c = 0;
            function preload(img) {
                var a = new Image();
                a.src = img;
                return a;
            }

            if (needed) {
                time0 = preload("image0.gif");
                time1 = preload("image1.gif");
                time2 = preload("image2.gif");
                time3 = preload("image3.gif");
                time4 = preload("image4.gif");
                time5 = preload("image5.gif");
                time6 = preload("image6.gif");
                time7 = preload("image7.gif");
                time8 = preload("image8.gif");
                time9 = preload("image9.gif");
            }

            function clickme() {
                // update image
                c += 1;
                // alert(c)
            }
        </script>
        <div align="center">
            <center>
                <img src="images/image0.gif" width="20" height="55" name="time0"> <a href="#" onMouseDown="return clickme()">
                    <img src="images/button.gif" border="0" width="96" height="55">
                    </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do you `//update image`?

Comment: he is actually asking how to do it. So curently he does not update it I guess.

Comment: Your markup is horribly incomplete, can you please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can and should take advantage of the fact, that only thing diferrent in the each umage name is number. So, you can store number and create any image name:

```
function getImage(id) {
    return "image"+id+".gif";
}
```

Then, you should have a way to acces the image that you want to change. Like adding `id` to he element:

```
<img id="changing" src="image0.png" />
```

There should be `onclick` used, not `onmousedown`. User may change his mind and hower the mouse away - that is not click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="clickme()" />
```

Finally, changing the image element:

```
var c=0;
var max = 9;
function clickme() {
   c++;
   if(c>max)
     c=0;   //looping back to zero
   docment.getElementById("changing").src = getImage(c);  //getImage is defined above
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on the image (`the-image`, for instance).

```
function clicme() {
    c += 1;
    document.getElementById('the-image')
        .setAttribute('src', 'image' + (c % 10) + '.gif');
}
```

Also there is no `href` element.  I think you meant to type `<a href`.